# Apache configuration Error

Tags: apache

I have issue on while run the command(httpd.exe -k install) in windows

> Installing the Apache2.2 service
>  The Apache2.2 service is
>   successfully installed.
>  Testing httpd.conf....
>  Errors reported
>   here must be corrected before the service can be started.
>   httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 85 of C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache
>   Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/Program
>   Files (x86)/Apache Software
>   Foundation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: The specified
>   procedure could not be found.

could you please help me on this ?

Thanks,
palani

Comment: What's unclear about "Syntax error on line 85"?

Comment: Please post your *httpd.conf*.